# how to change opencv trackbar appearance

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm developing a video player with OpenCV and C++, and I need a trackbar, but the opencv trackbar appearance is really ugly, anyone know any way to change the style of the trackbar and the font?

I'm under Windows and use Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: "I'm developing a video player with OpenCV" - arr, don't try to abuse it to make a videoplayer. there's no audio, no exact timing, it's simply not meant to be used that way.

Comment: You can't change the style or font of the trackbar